# How to use shell ,bash or sed command in this situation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

i have this file

```
name1
name2
name3
```

and how to achieve this result :

```
first
user:name1
end

first
user:name2
end

first
user:name3
end
```

i could use `sed 's#^#user:#'` to achieve

```
user:name1
user:name2
user:name3
```

but still not finish the job .any one help me .Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this easily with any number of tools. Awk comes to mind:

```
awk '{ print "first";
    print "user:", $0;
    print "end";
    print "" }' "$file"
```

Comment: One correction there, you forgot the file name at the end.

Comment: awk '{ print "first";
    print "user:", $1;
    print "end";
    print "" } file

Comment: @ArunSangal …sure, ok. I don't really view that as a gap, because OP didn't put the filename in their example `sed` statement either, and the `awk` command itself is complete. If no filename is provided, it will look at standard input.

Comment: @kojiro : how to change the answer into one line ,it needs 4 lines at now

Comment: @YOU why must it be one line? `awk '{print "first";print "user:", $0;print "end";print ""}' "$file"`

Comment: sed "s/^(.*)$/first\nuser:\1\nend\n/" yourfile

Answer (score 6):

To add the plain bash version:

```
while read line; do echo -e "first\nuser:$line\nend\n"; done < names.txt
```

Comment: For this specific input you could just do `printf 'first\nuser:%s\nend\n' $(<file)` (don't do that, it's a gag.)

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{printf "first\nuser:%s\nend\n\n", $0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

For example you have a file 1.txt having:

**$ cat 1.txt**

```
name1
name2
name3
shenzi
```

**$ sed "s/^(.*)$/first\nuser:\1\nend\n/" 1.txt**

```
first
user:name1
end

first
user:name2
end

first
user:name3
end

first
user:shenzi
end
```

Comment: Or perhaps `sed 's/.*/first\nuser:&\nend\n/' file`?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's#^\(.*\)$#first\nuser:\1\nend\n#' filename
```

`\( .. \)` -- store the matching string between parentheses to `\1` and then just create the string you want.

Comment: Please modify your answer to be helpful to future users and the OP and try to explain how your solution solves the problem